# How do I write a whole struct to a TEXT file with fwrite(), using structure pointers while the struct also contains char pointers?

Tags: c, database, file, struct

So I have a structure pointer named Cars leads to a struct which contains some char pointers that have text in them. And I am trying to write the whole structure into a text file using fwrite.

I have used calloc to allocate memory for the structures before trying to put text into the char * from the struct. Everything works fine, I can print any of the values of the struct. But I can't get them out to the text file. After I call fwrite, all I get in the text file is random text. I thought it would be trying to write stuff out in binary, but it's not that. Also, everytime the output slightly changes, it feels like it is returning some random adresses.
Here is my code:

```
int numberOfCars;

typedef struct
{
    char *plate;
    char *model;
    char *color;
    char *ownerName;
    char *problems;
    char *status;
    int year;

} car ;
void writeIntoDatabase(car *);
int main()
{
    car *Cars;
    numberOfCars=2;
    Cars=(car *)calloc(numberOfCars, sizeof(car));

    int i=0;
    (Cars+i)->plate="CJ23YOU";
    (Cars+i)->model="Mazda";
    (Cars+i)->color="Black";
    (Cars+i)->ownerName="Makro_And";
    (Cars+i)->problems="Rattling_noise";
    (Cars+i)->status="Fixed";
    (Cars+i)->year=2019;
    i++;
    (Cars+i)->plate="CJ65YOM";
    (Cars+i)->model="Volkswagen";
    (Cars+i)->color="White";
    (Cars+i)->ownerName="Mars Andy";
    (Cars+i)->problems="Rattling noise lllas";
    (Cars+i)->status="Pending";
    (Cars+i)->year=2009;

    writeIntoDatabase(Cars);
   // fprintf(DB_ptr,"%s",(Cars+i)->plate);
    printf("%s", (Cars+i)->plate);
    return 0;
}

void writeIntoDatabase(car *Cars)
{
    FILE *DB_ptr=fopen("carsDBwrite.txt","w");
    fwrite(Cars,sizeof(car),numberOfCars,DB_ptr);
    fclose(DB_ptr);
}
```

The output in my file is: dP@ lP@ rP@ xP@ ‚P@ ‘P@ ã  —P@ ŸP@ ªP@ °P@ ºP@ ÏP@ Ù

I would be really grateful for any suggestions and/or fixes, or any other way of making this work. I'm guessing fprint f would be one, but I didnt really want to use that as fwrite seemed as it would do the task better. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could change your `char *` fields to `char [MAX_STR]` if you want to store the actual data in the structure. Otherwise you'll need to write a function to serialise your data. As it is, you're just writing pointers to the file, which is useless.

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't write to a text file with `fwrite`, which is typically used to write to a binary file. One problem is that the integer values won't appear as human-readable textual values. And the pointers you write to the file will be meaningless. The data values such as `"Mazda"` and `"Black"` will be lost.

Comment: Why do you think ```fwrite``` would be more suitable here? And why do you not want to use ```fprintf```?

Comment: You should be using `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`, if you want to write a text file.

Comment: Our teacher likes things allocated dinamically, and this is for a graded project, so that's why I tried to have pointers so I only use the exact values. And as for why I did not use fprintf, fwrite seemed simpler if you could write an entire a struct at a time with it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is that fwrite write one *continuous* block of bytes to a file, however your struct contains pointers pointing elsewhere so what you are storing is basically the addresses of the strings instead of the strings themselves.

If you want to use fwrite you need to make the struct a continuous block of bytes, i.e. use char [] in your struct with fixed sizes.

E.g.

```
typedef struct
{
    char plate[MAXSIZE];
    char model[MAXSIZE];
    char color[MAXSIZE];
    char ownerName[MAXSIZE];
    char problems[MAXSIZE];
    char status[MAXSIZE];
    char year[MAXSIZE];  // if fwrite is to be used.

} car ;
```

Comment: The member `year` will still appear as garbage in the text file, which OP probably does not want.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to implement it like this. Our teacher likes things allocated dinamically, and this is for a graded project, so that's why I tried to have pointers so I only use the exact values.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel not if read it with fread

Comment: @AndersK: OP stated that the file is a "text file". Also, it has the extension `.txt`. Both of these facts imply that the text should be readable in a standard text editor.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes I see that now, well if he still wants to use fwrite he could convert int to a char array as well then it should be fine. But of course fprintf would have been a better choice rather than fwrite in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The function `fwrite` is generally used for writing to binary files, not text files.

Also, writing the values of the pointers to the file is not what you want. You want to write the strings to which the pointers point, not the values of the pointers themselves.

The function that you need is the function `fprintf`. That function allows you to pass a pointer to a string and to print the actual string, instead of the value of the pointer.

Here is an example program based on your posted code, with a few miscellaneous improvements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *plate;
    char *model;
    char *color;
    char *ownerName;
    char *problems;
    char *status;
    int year;

} car;

void writeIntoDatabase( car *cars, int num_cars );

int main( void )
{
    car cars[] = {
        {
            "CJ23YOU",
            "Mazda",
            "Black",
            "Makro_And",
            "Rattling_noise",
            "Fixed",
            2019
        },
        {
            "CJ65YOM",
            "Volkswagen",
            "White",
            "Mars Andy",
            "Rattling noise lllas",
            "Pending",
            2009
        }
    };

    writeIntoDatabase( cars, sizeof cars / sizeof *cars );

    return 0;
}

void writeIntoDatabase( car *cars, int num_cars )
{
    FILE *DB_ptr = fopen( "carsDBwrite.txt", "w" );
    if ( DB_ptr == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print one car per loop iteration
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++ )
    {
        fprintf(
            DB_ptr,
            "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n",
            cars[i].plate,
            cars[i].model,
            cars[i].color,
            cars[i].ownerName,
            cars[i].problems,
            cars[i].status,
            cars[i].year
        );
    }

    fclose(DB_ptr);
}
```

This program writes the following to the output file:

```
CJ23YOU
Mazda
Black
Makro_And
Rattling_noise
Fixed
2019
CJ65YOM
Volkswagen
White
Mars Andy
Rattling noise lllas
Pending
2009
```